# Adding values to an array in JavaScript loops

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, for-in-loop

I'm learning JavaScript and I used the loops to add some values to an array and then print theme and see the result. I have done this with different methods but I have a problem with one of them.

In the code below I can't think of a way to add values to an array using for/in the loop. How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function print(string){
    document.write(string+"<br>");
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    print("with for & for..in");
    var ma1Arr = [];

    for (i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
        ma1Arr.push(i);
    }
    for (i in ma1Arr) {
        print(ma1Arr[i]);
    }

    print("<hr>");
    print("with for & for..in  vice versa");
    var ma3Arr = [];
    i=20;
    for (i in ma3Arr){
        ma3Arr.push(i);
        i++
    }
    for (i=0; i<ma3Arr.length; i++){
        print(ma3Arr[i])
    }

    print("<hr>");

    print("with while & do..while");
    var ma2Arr = [];
    i = 30;
    do {
        ma2Arr.push(i);
        i++;
    } while (i < 40);
    i = 0;
    while (i < ma2Arr.length) {
        print(ma2Arr[i]);
        i++;
    }

    print("<hr>");
    print("with while & do..while vice versa");
    var ma4Arr = [];
    i = 40;
    while (i<=50){
        ma4Arr.push(i);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0
    do {
        print(ma4Arr[i]);
        i++;
    }while (i<ma4Arr.length);
</script>
```

Comment: The same way as you are already adding values in the for(x;y;z) look!

Comment: Hi, thank for your reply, I have updated the code above and put the code I'm trying to work on it in the code box, in "with for & for..in  vice versa" for adding values, how can I set the start and end range of the values that have to be added to Array?

Comment: @alfer :) Thank you do you have any idea how to fix this code?
I ran into a problem with "with for & for..in vice versa" method which I'm trying to add values with 'for/in' to an array and see the result with 'for'.

Answer (score 1):

for...in is used for objects like {a: 1, b: 4} and not for arrays. It is iterating all enumerable properties of the object such as a and b. But for arrays, you would need to go with for...of

for..in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

for...of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, so as I understood in this case "with for & for..in vice versa" in the code above I can't do it like this (add values to an array with 'for/in' and see the result with 'for').

Comment: No, because for...in and for...of iterate objects which already have data inside. that's the reason it's not working the way you think of it because there is no data to iterate. And these types of loops are not made for adding values to the same source you are iterating over.
if you use for..of on an empty array [] nothing will happen because it's empty. The same with for..in on an empty json-object {}

Answer (score 0):

```
 var array_name = [item1, item2, ...];
```

You put the values inside of the brackets... That is basically how you make an array for any language

Comment: Hi and thank you I want to make it harder by having an empty Array, and use Array.puch to add some values to it, basically for testing the loops but I ran into a problem with "with for & for..in vice versa" method which I'm trying to add values with 'for/in' and see the result with 'for'.